# What is the name of this Turkish chocolate?

Tags: chocolate, turkish-cuisine

[image]

They are from Turkey but have no idea what they are traditionally called. Although the box is generic, the contents are from a Turkish confectionery.

The brown and white ones are almonds covered in chocolate and the green and white ones are pistachios covered in white chocolate. While the dark, milk and white chocolate balls have bits of coffee bean in them.

[image] [image]

Comment: What mean by "name" - brand name, confectionary type, etc.? Also, why do you think they are from Turkey, because of the box? This is a Turkish delight box, so they are not the original content.

Comment: Fair points, I've made some changes

Comment: Why is it "Turkish" chocolate? They have chocolate covered nuts and coffee beans all over the world. What makes them different from the standard ones?

Comment: @Catija they have acid-curdled cheese all over the world, but in India it is called "paneer". I wouldn't be surprised if these turn out to be a thing in Turkey, with a distinct name.

Comment: @Catija, they taste really good compared to the supermarkets.

Comment: @Sourdough tasting good compared to a supermarket product doesn't make it a different product necessarily. We have specialty chocolatiers all over the world whose products taste better than brands purchased in stores. Also, rumtscho was not claiming this is cheese... there's no reason to get sassy at her.

Answer (score 5):

Alibaba has a site that let's you search by region, and indeed there is a [page for Turkish chocolate](https://www.alibaba.com/countrysearch/TR/chocolate-coated-almonds.html) including chocolate covered almonds.

As far as I can tell brand names seem to be [Tafe](http://www.tafegida.com/) and the ChocoVia and Dojo produced by [Besler](http://beslerkuruyemis.com.tr/en/stones-chocolate). Those brand names do not exclusively refer to chocolate covered almonds - which are called "chocolate covered almonds" on the Alibaba website, so that's no real help. But then I searched the company websites, and Tafe has a listing of "[Çikolata Kaplı Drajeler](http://www.tafegida.com/Kategori.aspx#CikolataKapliDrajeler)". As per Google translate "Çikolata Kaplı" means "chocolate covered" ("Drajeler" is translated as "drapes", I don't think this can be correct), so there is a good chance that these are actually called "chocolate covered almonds" in Turkey.

As rumtscho in the comment pointed out Drajeler is a loan word from the French. "Draje" means (according to the [first dictionary I could find](http://www.turkishdictionary.net/?word=draje)) both:

1. sugar-coated pill.
2. chocolate-coated raisin or nut.

Comment: Good find! There is a French word `dragée` which has entered many other languages as a loanword. It got its meaning slightly distorted in other languages, e.g. as "sugar pill" in Germany, and in the US, Rose Levi Beranbaum insists that it should be a metallic-covered sugar pearl, but admits that it has expanded to include all colors of sugar pearls. I knew it as "any small spherical candy" but, looking up the original meaning, it is [sugar-covered almond](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/drag%C3%A9e#fr). So if Turkey kept the original meaning, the term the OP is seeking would be Drajeler.

Comment: The English term is "dragee" but this is a much broader concept than just chocolate covered nuts or coffee beans. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragée

Comment: I can confirm "Draje" is the correct term, if you'll accept my childhood as a creditable source :)